# Error propagation vs standard deviation (pure statistics question, no software involved)

Tags: standard-deviation, uncertainty

First off, I'm new here, so I might have posted this question at the wrong place, but I don't really know where to post it and could really use some help here. Any insight would be appreciated.
My general confusion is about how to distinguish **propagated error of the mean** from the **standard deviation**. There is a chance that these terms are misused, but let me explain what I mean with the following example.

Say I record the temperature of a lake at three time stamps of a day (1am, 9am, 5pm). At each time stamp, temperature is measured multiple times (once at 1am, twice at 9am, 3 times at 5pm). Now I want to calculate the average temperature of the lake during that day **with uncertainty**. The dataset goes like this:

| Time | Temp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 am | 19 |
| 9 am | 21 |
| 9 am | 25 |
| 5 pm | 28 |
| 5 pm | 27 |
| 5 pm | 26 |

To calculate the average temperature of the day, I'll need to calculate the mean temperature at each time stamp and then average the 3 mean values. That part I get. What I'm not quite sure is how to present the uncertainty of the temperature of the day. I assume that the initial error is the standard deviation at each given time stamp (using Excel's STDEV.P function):

| Time | Mean Temp | Error |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 am | 19 | 0 |
| 9 am | 23 | 2.0 |
| 5 pm | 27 | 0.8 |

The average temperature of the day = (19+23+27)/3 = 23

Now, there are 2 approaches to present the uncertainty of the average.

Approach 1, calculate the standard deviation of the three hourly mean:
(in Excel)=STDEV.P(19, 23, 27)=3.3

Approach 2, propagate the errors from each time stamp (Bevington, 2003):
(in Excel)=sqrt(0^2+2.0^2+0.8^2)=2.2

Clearly, uncertainties calculated from these 2 methods are different. But what does each number stand for? My take on the first method is that 3.3 reflects how variable the temperature is at different hours of the day. But what does 2.2 from the second method represent then? How reliable is the calculated average value? Between 23.0 ± 3.3 and 23.0 ± 2.2, which one should I choose to report? Rather, is there any way to somehow "combine" these two types of uncertainty and report some sort of "integrated uncertainty"?

I don't know if this is a rookie question for most folks, but it has really been bothering me for quite some time and I crave a definitive answer. Thanks.